# How to uninstall wgcf completely on Linux

Tags: linux, vpn, fedora

I've installed wgcf for using warp on Linux from: https://github.com/ViRb3/wgcf
But it doesn't seem to suite my needs so I want to uninstall it. However there is no documentation that I could find for the same.

On startup, the follow VPN is enabled by default which cuts off my internet connection.

wgcf-profile VPN:
[image: wgcf-profile VPN]
Further, the VPN doesn't show up in the settings menu.

VPN menu in settings app:
[image: VPN menu in settings app]

I'm running
**OS**: Fedora Linux 37 (Workstation Edition)
**Host**: 81EV 81EV(Lenovo ideapad 530S-15)
**Kernel**: 6.1.13-200.fc37.x86_64

The developers in GitHub [state](https://github.com/ViRb3/wgcf/issues/142):

> Such questions are out of scope for this project, and should
> go to WireGuard and/or the Fedora team.

Comment: Have asked the authors?

Comment: @Toto https://github.com/ViRb3/wgcf/issues/142
"Such questions are out of scope for this project, and should go to WireGuard and/or the Fedora team"

Comment: Instead of answering in comments you should [edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1774416/edit) your question to add new info, clarifications etc. as I now did for you.

Answer (score 1):

As per the developer's statement in the [page you linked](https://github.com/ViRb3/wgcf/issues/142):

> There is nothing to install or uninstall, just the main binary file.

I.e. to remove it from your system you simply need to delete the binary itself.